# Little o notation meaning

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I’m taking calculus 1, and we defined little-o notation as following.

Let $h, r$ be real functions in one real variable, and $x_0 \in Dom(h) \cap Dom(r)$.
We define $σ(h(x))$ for $x\to x_0$ as the set of all the functions $r(x)$ such that $\lim_{x \to x_0} {\frac{r(x)}{h(x)}}=0$, so such that $r(x)$ is a bigger order infintesimal than $h(x)$

Let $f, g, h, r$ be real functions in one real variable, and $x_0 \in Dom(f) \cap Dom(f) \cap Dom(h) \cap Dom(r)$.
We write $f(x)=g(x)+σ(h(x))$ for $x\to x_0$ instead of writing $f(x)=g(x)+r(x)$ where $r(x)\in σ(h(x))$ for $x\to x_0$.

**Q1 - MEANING**

Is it correct to say that writing $f(x)=g(x)+σ(h(x))$ means “for $x \to x_0$, $g(x)$ is a good approximation of $f(x)$, with, as error, a function $r(x)$ which is an infinitesimal of bigger order than $h(x)$”?

**Q2 - PROVING THE EQUALITY**

If we have to prove that $f(x)=g(x)+σ(h(x))$, what do we really have to prove? Do we just prove that, if $σ(h(x))$ is nonempty (is it ever empty?) then for each function $r(x)\in σ(h(x))$ it’s true that $f(x)=g(x)+r(x)$?

Comment: Q2: You want to prove $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{h(x)} = 0$$

Comment: @AndrewZhang Ok thanks, so is it true that we could say also that $f(x)=g(x)+σ(h(x))$ means $f(x)-g(x)=σ(h(x))$, which means $f(x)-g(x) \in σ(h(x))$?

Comment: Yep you are right

Comment: @AndrewZhang ok thanks. Could you answer also question 1 and write it in an answer? In case, I’ll accept it.

Comment: Sure, but could you clarify what is an "infinitesimal of bigger order", I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @AndrewZhang an infinitesimal for $x\to x_0$ is a function $f$ such that $f(x)\to 0$ for $x \to x_0$. We say that, for two functions $g$ and $h$, $g$ is a bigger-order-infinitesimal than $h$ (and thus $h$ is a littler-order-infinitesimal than $g$) iff $\frac{g(x)}{h(x)} \to 0$ for $x\to x_0$

Comment: Basically if you have to infintesimals, it’s a way for saying which one “wins” on the other one, for example we know that $e^x$ is a bigger-order-infinitesimal than $x$, which is a bigger-order-infinitesimal than $logx$